# Call Rest ful service using HttpWebRequest and PUT Method

Tags: c#, jquery, rest, system.net.httpwebrequest, jquery-ajaxq

I am calling Rest API Http Method is "PUT", I am passing JSON data with "API-KEY". The same API request is working in jQuery Ajax call but not working in C# with HttpWebRequest.
Please see the Exception message: [Exception Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YGM8.jpg)
I am getting always error:

```
"The remote server returned as error: (400) Bad Request"
```

**Below is the C# code:**

```
StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder();
jsonData.Append(@"""name"": """ + name + '"' + ",");
jsonData.Append(@"""tin"": """ + tin + '"' + ",");
jsonData.Append(@"""tinType"": ""U"",");
jsonData.Append(@"""checks"": ""DT""");
string URL = @"https://api.dev.gmc-pharmacy.com/tesmdm/dev/tesmdm/taxvalidation/";
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.Method = "PUT";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = jsonData.Length;
    request.Headers.Add("GMC-API-KEY", "427b9574-27a6-4e21-8eea-c3e2a14e4ebe");
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData.ToString());        
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();        
    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    try
    {        
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string result;
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = rdr.ReadToEnd();
    }}
```

**Below is the working code in jQuery:**

```
$("#btnTINSubmit").click(function() { 
var URL = "https://api.dev.gmc-pharmacy.com/tesmdm/dev/tesmdm/taxvalidation/";

var data = {
    name: $("#txtSupplierName").val(), // Supplier Name
    tin: $("#txtSupplierTIN").val(),
    tinType: "U",
    checks: "DT"
};
$.ajax({
    //url: getExactPath('/Supplier/TaxValidate'),
    url: URL,
    type: "PUT",        
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("GMC-API-KEY ", "427b9574-27a6-4e21-8eea-c3e2a14e4ebe");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#TINResponse').text(data.matchInfoResponse[0].matchResultResponse.message);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('#TINResponse').text(xhr.response);

        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
});
```

Any Idea what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json data doesn't have the curly braces.
You're sending something like :

```js
"name": "AdithyaM",
"tin": "x",
"tinType": "U",
"checks": "DT"
```

when it should be like:

```js
{
    "name": "AdithyaM",
    "tin": "x",
    "tinType": "U",
    "checks": "DT"
}
```

that's probably the reason why your server is responding with a bad request response because it doesn't recognize the body of the request

Comment: oh my god, how stupid i am. I forgot it. Thanks for Help!

Comment: You're welcome buddy. Don't forget to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the json string format as below. Everything is perfect now.

```
jsonData.Append(@"{""name"": """ + name + '"' + ",");
jsonData.Append(@"""tin"": """ + tin + '"' + ",");
jsonData.Append(@"""tinType"": ""U"",");
jsonData.Append(@"""checks"": ""DT""}");
```